# I2C device address changing of MCP23017 I/O extender

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, gpio, i2c

When I connect all A0, A1 and A2 to ground, then my device address of the MCP23017 is 0x20 (constant).

But when I disconnect the A0 from ground, then the device address is switching between 20 and 21 everytime I check with the i2cdetect command?

Why isn't the device address constantly 21?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because the pin is floating.

Indeed the datasheet says of pins A0, A1, A2 "Hardware address pin. Must be externally biased."

This means you must tie each pin either low or high, you must not let them float.

Comment: Also check the errata (always a good idea, doubly so when microchip is involved), I have a feeling that there is a subtle trap in the write to enable hardware addressing on those parts.